# mysql left join sum two tables with rollup

Tags: mysql, left-join, rollup

i stack at mysql syntax where i have a table revenue with values

```
title_id | revenue | cost
1 | 10 | 5
2   10  5
3   10  5
4   10  5
1   20  6
2   20  6
3   20  6
4   20  6
```

and then i have table fund with values

```
title_id | interest
1 | 10
2   10
3   10
4   10
1   20
2   20
3   20
4   20
```

I want to join this two table using left join and rollup the values like this :

```
SELECT R.title_id, 
   R.revenue, 
   R.cost, 
   F.interest 
FROM   (SELECT title_id, 
           Sum(revenue) revenue, 
           Sum(cost)    cost 
    FROM   revenue 
    GROUP  BY revenue.title_id with rollup) r 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT title_id, 
                     Sum(interest) interest 
              FROM   fund 
              GROUP  BY title_id with rollup) f 
          ON r.title_id = F.title_id;
```

Output :

```
title_id | revenue | cost | interest
1   30  11  30
2   30  11  30
3   30  11  30
4   30  11  30
Total  120  44  null
```

But I want the output is :

```
title_id | revenue | cost | interest
1   30  11  30
2   30  11  30
3   30  11  30
4   30  11  30
Total  120  44  120
```

is this possible ?
Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the details scenario:

With Data Given:

```
select a.title_id,  sum(revenue), sum(cost),sum(interest) from
(select a.title_id,  sum(revenue) as revenue, sum(cost) as cost from
(select  1 title_id, 10 revenue , 5 cost UNION all
select 2,   10,  5 UNION all
select 3,   10,  5 UNION all
select 4,   10,  5 UNION all
select 1,   20,  6 UNION all
select 2,   20,  6 UNION all
select 3,   20,  6 UNION all
select 4,   20,  6) as a
GROUP BY title_id) as a

left JOIN

(select title_id, sum(interest) as interest from
(select 1 as title_id, 10 as interest UNION all
select 2,   10 UNION all
select 3,  10 UNION all
select 4,   10 UNION all
select 1,  20 UNION all
select 2,  20 UNION all
select 3, 20 UNION all
select 4,  20) as b
GROUP BY title_id ) as b
on a.title_id = b.title_id 
GROUP BY a.title_id
with ROLLUP
```

result:

```
1   30  11  30
2   30  11  30
3   30  11  30
4   30  11  30
    120 44  120
```

final query structure:

```
select a.title_id,  sum(revenue), sum(cost),sum(interest) from
(select a.title_id,  sum(revenue) as revenue, sum(cost) as cost from
(select * from revenue) as a
GROUP BY title_id) as a

left JOIN

(select title_id, sum(interest) as interest from
(select * from fund) as b
GROUP BY title_id ) as b
on a.title_id = b.title_id 
GROUP BY a.title_id
with ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. @reds

Comment: Thanks too for appreciating the answer... You are giving a clear question and it's nice.