# Cannot create Grand Total row after series of Union Selects in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

In our back-end, we segregate users residing in a given country and their associated data into distinct data sources.  For example, there is a data source for Singapore users and their transaction data, another for Japan users and their transaction data, and so on.

I created a query in Redash that builds two columns of data -- Country Name and Users -- and it works as intended.  However, I'm unable to add a Grand Total row to the bottom per the recommended methods in this article: http://webdevzoom.com/ultimate-guide-count-subtotal-grand-total-mysql/.

GROUP BY Country WITH ROLLUP doesn't produce a grand total row; rather, it just repeats the Signups count of the last row.  The recommendation in section III.1 of the article seems to be the most appropriate, but my implementation returns a "Table source1.all_signups doesn't exist" error on the alias.  For reference, Redash requires a data source to be selected when building a query, and my selected source is "source1."

Query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT "Country1" AS Country,
          count(id) AS Users
    FROM users
    UNION SELECT "Country2" AS Country,
                count(id) AS Users
    FROM source2.users
    UNION SELECT "Country3" AS Country,
                count(id) AS Users
    FROM source3.st_users
    UNION SELECT "Country4" AS Country,
                count(id) AS Users
    FROM source4.st_users
    ...
    UNION SELECT "CountryN" AS Country,
                count(id) AS Signups
    FROM sourceN.st_users
    GROUP BY Country
    ORDER BY Signups DESC
) AS all_signups
UNION SELECT
   "GRAND TOTAL" AS Country,
    SUM(Signups) AS Signups
FROM all_signups
```

Comment: Why do you segregate users? Is there a legal requirement?

Comment: For a few reasons.  First is that prices, content, and other site behavior is sufficiently different for distinct countries that we have separate site instances per country.  Second is that, as I understand it, data must be warehoused separately per regulations.  I have my questions, too, but suffice to say it is what it currently is.

Comment: Further info: I tested the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600828/mysql-left-join-sum-two-tables-with-rollup, but I still don't get the desired behavior...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, and would like to share my answer.  The key was to use variables.  I also changed the orientation to have the grand total at the top of the query (personal preference).  The final query looks like this:

```
SELECT @total_signups := FORMAT(SUM(Signups), 0)
FROM
(
    SELECT
          "Country1" AS Country,
          count(id) AS Signups
    FROM source1.users
    UNION SELECT
          "Country2" AS Country,
          count(id) AS Signups
    FROM source2.users
    ...
    UNION SELECT
          "CountryN" AS Country,
          count(id) AS Signups
    FROM sourceN.st_users
) AS total_calc;

SELECT
   "GRAND TOTAL" AS Country,
    @total_signups AS Signups
UNION SELECT
    Country,
    FORMAT(Signups, 0) AS Signups
FROM
(
    SELECT
          "Country1" AS Country,
          count(id) AS Signups
    FROM source1.users
    UNION SELECT
          "Country2" AS Country,
          count(id) AS Signups
    FROM source2.users
    ...
    UNION SELECT
          "CountryN" AS Country,
          count(id) AS Signups
    FROM sourceN.st_users
    ORDER BY Signups DESC
) AS all_signups;
```

It's a beast of a query, but it gets the job done!  For reference, we're on MySQL 5.7.